# Sort the files in a list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

glob.glob(file_naming)

Doing this gives me two files:

```
['/srv/tmp/what/123_aaa_bbb_20190110043711.XML',
 '/srv/tmp/what/234_xxx_yyy_20190110043710.XML']
```

How can I sort them in order of the last part( 20190110043711)?
I need a result like:

```
['/srv/tmp/what/123_aaa_bbb_20190110043710.XML',
 '/srv/tmp/what/234_xxx_yyy_20190110043711.XML']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sorted`:

```
>>> sorted(l,key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[-1]))
['/srv/tmp/what/234_xxx_yyy_20190110043710.XML', '/srv/tmp/what/123_aaa_bbb_20190110043711.XML']
>>>
```

Comment: after using this, it is still not in order: `/srv/tmp/tmporxECk/T052_UK_20190118113012.XML
/srv/tmp/tmporxECk/T681_UK_20190110043710.XML
/srv/tmp/tmporxECk/T685A_UK_20190118113012.XML
/srv/tmp/tmporxECk/T683S_UK_20190118113012.XML
/srv/tmp/tmporxECk/T682I_UK_20190118113012.XML
/srv/tmp/tmporxECk/T009B_UK_20190110043710.XML` This  is the order that I am getting. The last part is the date and time stamp and I want to sort according to that @U9-Forward

Answer (score 0):

[Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)
you can see this post for natural sorting.

you can use https://pypi.org/project/natsort/ -- natsort 
pasted an example below

```
 a = ['Apple', 'apple15', 'Banana', 'apple14,689', 'banana']
 natsorted(a, alg=ns.REAL | ns.LOCALE | ns.IGNORECASE)
```